# Show $\ln x \le x \ln x, x > 0$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

Show $\ln x \le x \ln x$, when $x > 0$.

Using exponentiation, this is
$$
x \le x^x.
$$
Doing a case by case analysis for the cases 
\begin{align}
(1) &: x \in (0,1), \\
(2) &: x = 1, \\
(3) &: x > 1,
\end{align}
gives the results.
Is there another way?

Comment: What do you mean: *Is there any other way*? That is, without exponentiating or without breaking into cases? At any rate...just *divide*!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions $\ln x$ and $x\ln x$ are continuous. So $f(x)=x\ln x -\ln x$ can only change sign where $f(x)=0$. This happens at $x=1$. Now use "test" values, say $x=1/e$ and $x=e$. (Possibly very close to your cases analysis.)

Answer (score 4):

If $f(x)=\ln x-x\ln x$ then $f(1)=f'(1)=0$ and $f''(x)\le0$ for all $x>0$.

Answer (score 1):

It is well known that $1+x\leq e^x$, thus:

$$x<e^x$$
$$\log(x)<\log(e^x)=x$$